# using tedious connection,need to get the total data

Tags: reactjs, es6-promise, tedious, es6-module-loader

hai I am new to tedious and Es-6,It may be a silly question but I am struggling,
I want  the total data in a array, using tedious connections here is my code:

```jsx
 getZipData() {
        var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
        Request = require('tedious').Request;
        var config = {
            userName: 'xx',
            password: 'xxxx',
            server: 'xxx', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
            options: {
                database: 'xxxxx',
                rowCollectionOnDone:'true'
            }
        }
        var connection = new Connection(config);
        var jsonArray = [];
        connection.on('connect', function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }

            var sql = "SELECT * FROM xxxxx";
            return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            var request = new Request(sql,
                (err, rowCount, rows)=>{
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("rows");
                        console.log(rowCount + 'rows');
                    }
                });
                request.on('row', (columns)=>{
                        var rowObject = {};
                        columns.forEach((column)=> {
                            rowObject[column.metadata.colName] = column.value;
                        });
                        jsonArray.push(rowObject);
                    });
                connection.execSql(request);
                request.on('done', function(rowCount, more) {
                    console.log(rowCount + ' rows returned');
                    alert("jsonArray2:"+jsonArray);
                    resolve(jsonArray)
                });

            });
    })
}
componentWillMount() {
    this.getZipData().then(function(resolved){
        console.log(resolved);
        alert("data:"+resolved);
    }).catch(function(rejected){
        console.log(rejected);
    })
}
```

when i add the  request.on('done', function(rowCount, more)  also i didn't get any data can any one give the solution for it,
I want the total data to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calling resolve before your query has been executed:

```
var jsonArray = [];

// Register callback for row event
request.on('row', (columns)=>{
  var rowObject = {};
  columns.forEach((column)=> {
    rowObject[column.metadata.colName] = column.value;
  });

  jsonArray.push(rowObject);
});

// Call resolve before executing request
resolve(jsonArray);

connection.execSql(request);
```

The [docs](http://pekim.github.io/tedious/api-request.html) mention a `done` event that indicates a request has completed:

```
request.on('done', function (rowCount, more, rows) {
  // Call resolve here instead?
  resolve(jsonArray);
});
```

**Disclaimer**: I've haven't actually used [Tedious](https://github.com/pekim/tedious), but from the docs linked this looks like what you're looking for.

Comment: getting error :"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '
then' of undefined".

Comment: i change the code as above but i didn't get any data